# Why doesn't inout pass by reference?

Tags: swift

I'm doing something like this:

```
someFunction(&myClass)
```

where someFunction sorts an array on myClass.

```
someFunction(inout someclass:ClassA) {
 someClass.sort({$0.price > $1.price})  
}
```

If I print myClass after the function call, I notice the array is still unsorted.  From what I know, Swift passes values by copy.  But when I use inout, shouldn't it change to pass by reference?

Comment: Can you show a (small) *complete, self contained* example?

Comment: That's exactly what it's doing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30541244/what-does-a-ampersand-mean-in-the-swift-language

Comment: I posted some additional code. @snowman4415's answer makes sense.  I tested and that is the case.  I'm actually doing a sort() on an array.

Comment: Also note that if you actually were sorting on a class and not an array, you would not need the `inout`, as `inout` is only for assigning a new value to `someclass` and not modifying it in place.  Conversely, if you were sorting on a `struct` (likely), you could assign the result to the `inout` param to get the desired effect.

Comment: Could you mark answer if you find one satisfactory?

Comment: Everyone's just telling him what he already knows. He's not asking the difference between reference and value types. He's asking why "inout" does not produce the same results as explicitly passing a pointer as a parameter to the function. Explicitly passing a POINTER to a value type.

Answer (score 4):

This is because class instances and functions are reference types. Ints, structs, and everything else are value types. When you pass a reference type into a function as a parameter, you are already going to be referencing that instance. When you pass a value type as a parameter, the function gets a copy of that variable (by default), so `inout` is *usually* (see edit) only needed if you want to alter a **value** type from inside of a function.

Altering a class instance without `&` or `inout`:

[image]

**More details**

When you create a reference type `var t = myClass()`, you're really creating a variable `t` that is a pointer to a `myClass` instance in memory. By using an ampersand `&t` in front of a reference type, you are really saying "*give me the pointer to the pointer of a `myClass` instance*"

More info on reference vs value types: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27366050/580487

**EDIT**

As was pointed out in the comments, you can still use `inout` with reference types if you want to alter a pointer, etc, but I was trying to shed light on the general use case.

Below is an example of sorting an array inside of a function:

[image]

Comment: "so inout is needed only if you want to alter a value type from inside of a function." Not true, you need inout with reference types if you want to alter a reference -- i.e. if you want to change it to point to another object. Of course, all reference types are "value types", where the only value is a reference, so technically your statement is correct, but then it would be a trivial statement so that's probably not what you meant.

Comment: @snowman4415: I tested and that is the case.  I'm actually doing a sort() on an array.  I don't see the sorted values when I reference the class after and outside of the function call.

Comment: @4thSpace check out my edit. `sort` does not alter the array in place, you need to reassign the return value.

Comment: Please put code examples as text instead of images. Better for copying the code for anyone to try.

Answer (score 0):

If you post your code here, it would be more meaningful. BTW, look at below links that might helpful for you,

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID173

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID545