# Is it possible to pass attributes of a class as parameters? (SWIFT)

Tags: swift

So...what I mean is:

```
class Test {
var a: String?
var b: String?
}
```

is it possible to have a function that updates either a or b based on an argument?

a bit like

```
func updateTest(_ attribute: Test.attribute,_ updateTo: String){

attribute = updateTo
}
```

then call like:

```
var test = Test()
updateTest(test.b, "foo")
print(test.b) // foo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with an [`inout` parameter](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID545):

```
func updateTest(_ attribute: inout String?, _ updateTo: String) {
    attribute = updateTo
}
```

and then:

```
updateTest(&test.b, "foo")
```

For the meaning of `&` here, see [What does an ampersand (&) mean in the Swift language?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30541244/3425536).

Comment: Thanks tuple! Helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that. But you could do

```
func updateTest(_ testClass: Test,_ updateTo: String){
    testClass.b = updateTo
}
```

So your code would be

```
var test = Test()
updateTest(test, "foo")
print(test.b) // foo
```