# Set the value of multiple variables

Tags: swift, label

In a UIStackView, I have four labels corresponding to four `IBOutlet` variables named `lbl_0`, `lbl_1`, `lbl_2`, `lbl_3`.

Sometimes, I need to set their value to an empty string. I thought I could do something "flashy" like the following:

```
// inside a loop body
cell["lbl_"+i].text = ""
```

but it seems I can't ("no subscript members" error).

So, aside from setting the value this way:

```
cell.lbl_0.text = ""
cell.lbl_1.text = ""
cell.lbl_2.text = ""
cell.lbl_3.text = ""
```

is there any other way to set the value of these labels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**@IBOutletCollection**

You can connect each label to the same Outlet Collection.
To achieve this, drag and drop the first label into the `UIViewController`, then in the popover dialog set the Connection to Outlet Collection and Name to `labelCollection`. This will create an array where you can add the other labels.

And finally:

```
for label in labelCollection {
    label.text = ""
}
```

or

**UILabel subviews**

*Warning: This will access all labels in the specified view.*

```
for label: UILabel in self.view.subviews.filter({ $0 as? UILabel }) {
    label.text = ""
}
```

Comment: This sounds interesting, I was starting to use the Mirror API to get the members of the custom cell containing the labels...

Comment: Update: the second accesses all labels. What if I want to access only the second, the third and the fourth?

Comment: If you have labels in the view that you don't want to edit, I would discourage the use of the latter for-loop and instead go for the `IBOutletCollection`.

Answer (score 1):

My initial thought was that maybe you could do something like

```
cell.lbl_0.text = cell.lbl_1.text = cell.lbl_2.text = cell.lbl_3.text = ""
```

But, as it says here in [this fine answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26155631/4063602)

> You don't. This is a language feature to prevent the standard unwanted side-effect of assignment returning a value

So...it doesn't seem so, not without using an `Outlet Collection` as @laffen suggests at least.

But as @matt-gibson suggest in the answer I'm linking to, you can use tuples like so:

```
(cell.lbl_0.text, cell.lbl_1.text, cell.lbl_2.text, cell.lbl_3.text) = ("", "", "", "")
```

Which is a tad shorter, but not what you was hoping for I guess :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a tag to each label and then use `UIView`'s `viewWithTag` to extract the labels from the `UIStackView`.