# Swift / transferring objective c code / iterate in for loop / Type XY has no subscript members

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following for loop in Objective C code and am trying to transfer it to Swift.

```
double lastAx[4],lastAy[4],lastAz[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
lastAx[i] = lastAy[i] = lastAz[i] = 0;
}
```

My Code so far gives me the error: `Type Double has no subscript members`

```
var lastAx:Double = 4
var lastAy:Double = 4
var lastAz:Double = 4

    for i: Int32 in 0  ..< 4  {
        lastAx[i] = lastAy[i] = lastAz[i] = 0
    }
```

What am I missing? Help is very appreciated.

Comment: lastAx is a number in your code. Do you want to declare it as an array instead?

Comment: code updated. sorry, didn't realized it is missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare `lastAx, lastAy, lastAz` as arrays with [init(count:repeatedValue:)](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/type/Array/#init-count_repeatedvalue_) initializer:

```
var lastAx = [Double](count:4, repeatedValue: 0)
var lastAy = [Double](count:4, repeatedValue: 0)
var lastAz = [Double](count:4, repeatedValue: 0)
```

Also you will not have to zero them because these initializers set all of the values to zeros.  You won't need the loop from the original code, so just delete it.

Comment: first of all: thank you, but this gives me: `Cannot subscript a value of type '[Double]' with an index of type 'Int32'`

Comment: This is because in Swift array's index has type Int (64-bit signed integer), not Int32. Just remove `: Int32` in your code. And you do not need to nullify arrays at all since they are nullified during initialization (see `repeatedValue` option).

Comment: deleting the `: Int32`gave me: `Cannot assign value of type '()' to type 'Double'`

Comment: and with nillify you mean deleteting the `= 0` ?

Comment: vacawama changes did deleted the `; needed` error. thank you. but still: `Cannot assign value of type '()' to type 'Double'`

Comment: @DavidSeek, does your code match the updated code in the answer? That should work for you.

Comment: You receive this error because Swift does not support Multiple variable assignment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26155523/multiple-variable-assignment-in-swift

Comment: I have updated my question, so it gets a little more clear.

Comment: @Avt okay I see, what are my option to get it working?

Comment: @DavidSeek, you don't need the `for` loop from the original code.  That was initializing those arrays to zeros, but the initializers in the above answer already do that.  Just get rid of the `for` loop and you're done.

Comment: ah okay. well. than thank you very much for your effort. @vacawama if you want too, you can summarize your answer, so i can at least give you an upvote. thank you guys