# increment Error in swift 3

Tags: swift

Hello I am using swift and when I am trying to use and increment it outputs a pair of parenthesis.

```
var initialScore = 8
let TotalScore = initialScore+=1
```

The error comes out as

Constant 'TotalScore' inferred to have type '()', which may be unexpected

Please help me!

Comment: let TotalScore = initialScore+1 remove =

Comment: It's *either* `let TotalScore = initialScore + 1`... or just `initialScore += 1` *then* `let TotalScore = initialScore`. It doesn't do the same thing, be careful.

Comment: More or less the same issue as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26155523/multiple-variable-assignment-in-swift: the assignment operators in Swift do not return a value.

Comment: Thankyou so so much it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have small issue that is connected with `=`. To solve youre problem try :

```
var initialScore = 8
let TotalScore = initialScore+1
```

If you would like to increment value by 1 you should not use = before 1 in you're case.

Small example where you should use `+=` together.

```
var a = 1
a += 2
```