# How to assign value after increment Swift?

Tags: swift, swift5, swift-playground

```
var str = ["Franc": 2]
var a = 1
str["Franc"] = a += 1
print(str)
```

When I try this code i get an error on line "str["Franc"] = a += 1" that  is "Cannot assign value of type '()' to type 'Int?'"
How to solve this. I need it in single line
Thank you in advance

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [Multiple variable assignment in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26155523/multiple-variable-assignment-in-swift).

Comment: See also [increment Error in swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39704971/increment-error-in-swift-3)

Comment: What I mean is set value of "a" to dictionary and then increment. How can it possible in one line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this directly only in Objective C:

**In Objective C:**

```
[str setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:a+=1] forKey:@"Franc"];
```

**In Swift**

```
str["Franc"] = a
a += 1
```

Comment: This is the only possible way?

Answer (score 1):

You can increment number like this

```
str["Franc"]! = a ; a += 1
```

assign value

```
var str = ["Franc": 2]
str["Franc"]! += 1
```

and now `str["Franc"]` will returns 3

And if you want to avoid force unwrapping

```
str["Franc"] = (str["Franc"] ?? 0) + 1
```

Also you can do it using `if let`

```
if let num = str["Franc"] as? Double {
    str["Franc"] = num + 1
}
```

Comment: What I mean is set value of "a" to dictionary and then increment. How can it possible in one line

Comment: `str["Franc"]! = a ; a += 1` thats how you can do it in one line ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this in a single line:

```swift
var str = ["Franc": 2]
var a = 1
str["Franc"] = a 
a += 1
print(str)
```

Comment: You didn't increment `a` in your answer, and it looks like it is something OP wants.

Comment: What I mean is set value of "a" to dictionary and then increment. How can it possible in one line

Comment: Ok my mistake miss read the question, so you want to add a to the dictionary then increment the dictionary value or then  increment a?

Comment: I don't think you can do both in a single line.