# Declare and initialize variables or constants on the same line in swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift

Well i see this is valid swift code:

`var R, G, B, opacity: Double`

Since this code will run execute with no problems, Say i wanted to set all the above variables to 0.0, How would it be declared and initialized ? because `let R, G, B, opacity: Double = 0.0` throws a **Type annotation missing in pattern** error

I know in Python

`a = b = c = d = e = g = h = i = j = True`

or Javascript

`var a = b = c = d = e = g = h = i = j = true`

Comment: var R = 0.0, G = 0.0 , B = 0.0,  opacity = 0.0

Comment: var R, G, B, opacity: Double

Comment: This was already discussed here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26155523/multiple-variable-assignment-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

> The assignment operator (=) doesn’t return a value, to prevent it from being mistakenly used when the equal to operator (==) is intended. – https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html

```swift
let (R, G, B, opacity) = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

is the cleanest you can do, but you really should make a struct.

```swift
struct Color {
  var (r, g, b, opacity) = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can define multiple variable of same type like below:

```
var R, G, B, opacity: Double
```

Or

```
var R = 0.0, G = 0.0, B = 0.0, opacity= 0.0
```